# Travel to Russia under current conditions: Do I need a visa if I reside in country X as citizen of Y (but would not require one as citizen of Z)?

Tags: visas, russia, italian-citizens, german-residents, brazilian-citizens

Russia has recently lifted travel bans for nationals and residents of some countries (see, e.g., [here](https://www.travelinglifestyle.net/russia-reopening-borders-with-restrictions/)). I happen to reside in one of these countries (Germany) and as an EU citizen (Italy) automatically have a residence permit. In addition, I have dual citizenship and also hold a passport of a country (Brazil) for which a visa is not required to travel to Russia under normal circumstances, but which is currently still affected by the Russian travel ban.

Can I travel to Russia under the current circumstances? Do I need a visa as an Italian citizen? Or can I enter Russia without a visa with my Brazilian passport (along with adequate evidence of residence in Germany)?

Comment: As you hold an italian passport, [Italian passport requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Italian_citizens) apply for you. I would personally use the italian passport as you could seek diplomatic support more easily by going to an EU consulate/embassy, rather than a brazilian one. It might be also mentioning that there may be some scruteny for using your Brazilian passport due to the Brazilian COVID variant (although [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Brazilian_citizens) suggests nothing of the sort.)

Comment: @Boolean Please answer in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166131/travel-to-russia-under-current-conditions-do-i-need-a-visa-if-i-reside-in-count/171265#comment413501_166131):

As you hold an Italian passport, Italian passport requirements apply for you. I would personally use the Italian passport as you could seek diplomatic support more easily by going to an EU consulate/embassy, rather than a Brazilian one. It might be also mentioning that there may be some scrutiny for using your Brazilian passport due to the Brazilian COVID variant (although [Wikipedia suggests nothing of the sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Brazilian_citizens).)